# C# abrir y cerrar las conexiones

Tags: c#, bucle-for

He desarrollado una aplicación que lee una serie de registros y dentro de esta lectura hay un lazo que va escribiendo... está un poco resumido para visualizar mejor el problema de Abrir y Cerrar la conexión (conex)

```
      conex.Open();

        while (registros.Read())
        {

            kpt1 = registros["Val_Act1"].ToString();
            kpt2 = registros["Val_Act2"].ToString(); 
            kpt3 = registros["Val_Act3"].ToString(); 

            kp1= float.Parse(kpt1); // valorparametros[0] = kp1;
            kp2 = float.Parse(kpt2); //valorparametros[1] = kp2;
            kp3 = float.Parse(kpt3); //valorparametros[2] = kp3;

            conex.Close();

            if (mes == 1)
            {
                (((Instrucciones similares para cada mes)))
            }
            if (mes == 2)
            {
                 (((Instrucciones similares para cada mes)))

            }
            if (mes == 6)
            {
            String modifica;             

            MessageBox.Show("calcula el valor 1");
            kpac = GrillaModResulta[0, n].Value.ToString();                 
            valact = float.Parse(kpac);
            sumact = (kp6 + valact) / 2;

            MessageBox.Show("calcula el valor 2");
            kpmi = GrillaModResulta[1, n].Value.ToString();
            valmin = float.Parse(kpmi);
            summin = (kp18 + valmin) / 2;

            modifica = "UPDATE Historico SET Val_Act6 = @sumact, Val_Min6 =@summin WHERE Empresa ='" + empresa + "'";
            SqlCommand escribe = new SqlCommand(modifica, conex);
            escribe.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sumact", kpac);
            escribe.Parameters.AddWithValue("@summin", kpmi);
                 conex.Open();
                 escribe.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 conex.Close(); 
                 n = n + 1; kpac = n.ToString();                 
            }       
        }
```

Me sale un mensaje que dice que no puede leer porque la conexión está cerrada, en el "Read()" luego de la primera corrida.

Si le quito el conex.Open() antes de "escribe.ExecuteNonQuery" me dice que está abierta una lectura (en el "escribe") y debo cerrarla antes.

Si le quito el conex.Close() luego del "escribe" igual me dice que está cerrada para una lectura en el "Read()" y debo abrirla.

El manejo en este caso de un lazo de lectura con lazos internos de escritura... donde se ubicarían los Open y los Close.

Muchas gracias las sugerencias

Answer (score 4):

Veo varios fallos , que en mi humilde opinion tienes que evitar:

1. No abras una conexion si no vas a hacer nada con ella. Me explico, que sentido tiene abrir la conexion al inicio si hasta el final no la usas.
2. No entiendo por que cierras la conexion en las siguientes 10 lineas.No las has utilizado para nada
3. Te falta un control de excepciones, muy importante este apartado.

Te recomiendo que la parte del Update lo hagas como recomienda Microsoft un [ejemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand__ctor_System_String_System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_)

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(..., conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using(DataReader dr = cmd.Execute()) // Ejecuta el comando que quieras :)  
        {
             ...
        {
    }
}
```

De esta manera los recursos se cierran/destruyen incluso si ha habido un excepcion.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, pero creo que hay un detalle que no parece que expliqué bien. Hay un Read() como proceso principal y dentro del While (registros Read()), he puesto algunos if (mes==n) que los necesito por cada mes del año. Dentro de "While" inicialmente se leen registros de la BD-SQL, para que luego, dentro de los "if", se vayan colocando algunos de los datos como los necesito. Fundamentalmente, por lo que hasta ahora entiendo, se debe abrir la conexión para leer los datos (en el "while") y luego se debe cerrar (??) para luego nuevamente abrir la conexión para escribir (en el "if")

Comment: No se si te he entendido bien espero que me corrijas. Antes del bucle `while (registros.read())` la conexion ya estaba abierta porque la usabas para obtener los datos de BD y luego si se cumple la condicion de tu `if (mes == 6)` haces un `update` dentro del bucle no?. Si lo que he entendido es correcto la mejor forma es cuando acabas un tarea(Leer de BD o Update de BD) abres y cierras la conexion pero solo cuando la vayas a usar, nada de abrirlo al inicio de tu programa y cerrarlo al final cada cosa tiene su momento, controlando excepciones y de la forma que te he comentado antes.

Comment: Lo que comentas es lo correcto. Ahora bien, funciona cuando abro- ((Update)) y cierro, pero cuando voy a leer ((Reader)), a que momento abro? Antes del While? y en que línea de código crees que debo colocar Close. He probado ponerle en algunas líneas, pero algún tipo de error se genera y son algunos por eso no te los detallo por este medio.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, las operaciones que intentas son bastante complejas. En la medida de lo posible yo te recomendaría una de dos:

- Crear un `Stored Procedure` donde le dejes a SQL Server la tarea de calcular valores y hacer los `update`s que necesites y solo hacer una conexión a la base de datos:

  ```
  using (SqlConnection conex = /* tu conexión */)
  {
      using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("NombreDelSP", conex))
      {
          cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmnd.Parameters.Add(...);
          conex.Open();
          cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Si no devuelve resultados o
          cmnd.ExecuteReader();   // si sí
      }
  }
  ```
- Ejecutar una consulta que te traiga **todos** los registros que necesitas en un `DataTable` y cerrar la conexión; después recorrer cada `DataRow` que contenga (en un `for` o `foreach`), realizar tus operaciones y hasta entonces *crear* y cerrar una nueva conexión específicamente para el `update` que necesites:

  ```
  DataTable dt;
  using (SqlConnection conex = /* tu conexión */)
  {
      using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ...", conex))
      {
          cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          cmnd.Parameters.Add(...);
          conex.Open();
          using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmnd))
          {
              dt = new DataTable();
              da.Fill(dt);
          }
      }
  }
  if (dt != null)
  {
      foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
      {
          // Operaciones
          using (SqlConnection conex = /* tu conexión */)
          {
              using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE...", conex))
              {
                  cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                  cmnd.Parameters.Add(...);
                  conex.Open();
                  cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Bueno, creo que expliqué mejor mi plan, y ahora se visualizan algunas alternativas de los que saben bien el tema. Si el problema fundamental parece ser que no puedo "anidar" una escritura (Update) dentro de una lectura (Read), entonces separaré las dos mediante una tabla auxiliar donde se guardará la lectura para luego escribirlo (es lo lógico). La cantidad de datos no es grande así que suena factible aunque no llegue a ser óptimo. Les avisó como lo hice pero no sé en que tiempo. Agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

El código que pones es muy resumido y dificulta comprenderlo de manera correcta para poder ayudarte.

Por lo que veo, `registros.Read()` va iterando un resultado de un `select` a la BD y luego hace ciertos cálculos y luego toma el registro `n` de una grilla y va calculando un máximo y un mínimo y lo guarda un un registro filtrado por "empresa" ... difícil saber si la empresa es igual o diferente para cada registro.

Como una primera aproximación al problema, eliminaría todos los `open()` y `close()` y usaría using.

```
using(conex = openConnection()) {
  // lleno la viriable registros
  while (registros.Read()) {
    // codigo
  }
}
```

Con el using, al salir, se ejecuta el `Dispose()` de la conexión de forma automática cerrando la conexión a la BD.

Por otro, el problema del Read() es que deja (y necesita) la conexión a la BD abierta... si se cierra falla.

Una segunda aproximación es usar 2 usings, una para el Read() y otra para el Command del update a la BD.

```
using (conex = openConnection()) {
  // lleno la viriable registros
  while (registros.Read()) {
    // codigo
    using(conex2 = openConnection()) {
      // codigo update de la bd
    }
    // resto del codigo
  }
}
```

De esta forma la conexión del `Read()` no se cierra hasta el final (y mas importante, te aseguras que luego del último Read() se cierre, sino tb te va a generar problemas a posteriori).

Espero que te sea de utilidad

Comment: Bueno, es cierto que está resumido, pero lo has comprendido bien. La empresa es la misma hasta completar las iteraciones. También has dado con el problema (que es el tema único de la pregunta) del cierre y apertura de la conexión. En mi caso "conex". El using no resulta por lo que dices... se cierra luego de las instrucciones (pasa el "if", se cierra "conex") y el siguiente "Read()"  lo encuentra cerrado y se detiene la ejecución. Voy a probar el uso de "conex" y conex1" y a ver que pasa.

Comment: Hola a todos. La solución para mi caso fue: abrir la base de datos, leer los datos y guardarlos en un arreglo "string[,] valores = new string[10,30];", luego cerrar la base de datos para lectura y abrir nuevamente la base de datos para escritura, obviamente luego cerrar la base de datos. Este proceso cada vez que se quiera guardar los datos. Funcionó muy bien. Aprecio la ayuda...